# I need to combine 2 queries into one on query 1 area to query 2 description and query 1 empl to query 2 employee_id

Tags: sql

I have the following 2 queries and their output.

Query 1

```
select
types,area,avg(time2)as time,empl,whse,des
from(select  l.control_number_2 as types, l.control_number as area,
sum(round(cast(DATEDIFF(ss, l.start_tran_time,l.end_tran_time) /60.0 as float),2))over (partition by l.control_number) time2, l.employee_id as empl, l.wh_id as whse ,
(select distinct lu.description from t_lookup lu where lu.description = l.control_number) as des
from t_cp_work_area_log l 
where start_tran_date >= '2010-05-04 00:00:00.000' 
) t
group by whse, empl,types, area,des
```

Query 2

```
select t.client_code,t.tran_type, t.employee_id,count(t.hu_id)as plts, lu.description,cs.prod_id, ps.fixed_std, ps.dynamic_std,(fixed_std/sum(fixed_std) OVER (PARTITION BY lu.description)) "fs_summed",fixed_std/60 as stand_per_min
from t_tran_log t, t_lookup lu, t_cp_client_prod_stds cs, t_cp_prod_stds ps
where lu.text = t.tran_type and lu.source in ('t_cp_prod_stds','t_cp_work_area')
and t.client_code = cs.client_code and cs.prod_id = ps.prod_id and ps.work_type = lu.text and
t.start_tran_date >= '2010-05-04 00:00:00.000' 
group by t.tran_type, t.client_code,t.employee_id, cs.prod_id,lu.description,ps.fixed_std, ps.dynamic_std
```

Output query 1

```
types area time empl whse des
Inventory ADJ 7 TA C1 ADJ
LOG-ON LOG-ON 55.4 TA C1 LOG-ON
Outbound LDG 62.7 TA C1 NULL
Outbound PCKG 11.45 TA C1 NULL
Receiving RCVG 8.73 TA C1 RCVG
```

Output query 2

```
client_code tran_type emplyee_id plts description prod_id fixed_std dynamic_std fs_summed stand_per_min
826 853 TA 2 ADJ 13 50 50 1 0.833333
810 114 TA 1 RCVG 4 50 50 0.555555556 0.833333
826 114 TA 1 RCVG 11 40 40 0.444444444 0.666666
```

Comment: Use the formatting options to make your queries readable. Most people won't bother to read this otherwise.

Comment: You question is not very clear so providing help is hard. Have you considered using "Union"? If yes, why did it not help? Also, try formatting the examples using the "code" tool in the editor.

Comment: What database system? what version??

Comment: Thanks a million!  That was fast and exactly what I needed.  Obviously I am rather new to sql and thought that it would be an easy answer.  I was reluctant to ask for help but after trying multiple failed attempts on my own I am really pleased that I did.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Although I barely understand your question, I think you are just asking how to do a join.

```
SELECT *  -- better to explicitly list the columns you need here
  FROM
  ( <text of query1> ) q1
  JOIN
  ( <text of query2> ) q2
  ON q1.area = q2.description AND q1.empl = q2.employee_id
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That was fast and exactly what I needed. Obviously I am rather new to sql and thought that it would be an easy answer. I was reluctant to ask for help but after trying multiple failed attempts on my own I am really pleased that I did. Thanks again